# Style href to be on same position as relative element

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i am using position relative to set some part of my code, problem is that there is a href what is in HTML before class shorttext so it should be it parent. But dispite this fact a href part is below (check image) how can i fix it and put  on same position as shorttext ?

p.s.It will be cool if its possible without position relative or absolute

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="left">
    <img src="images/slider.png">
    <a href="#"><span class="shorttext"><h4>V posledných dnech se událo mnoho změn, které byli velice výrazné. Proto neváhajte a podívete se i vy na to, co se vlastne zmenilo a nebo nezměnilo kdo vi... </h4></span></a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#news .left{
      width: 415px;
      background-color: #2d2d2d;
      height:229px;
      display:block;
      float:left;
      margin: 0px;
      float: left;    
    }

#news .left a{
    display: block;    
}

.shorttext{
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    width: 415px;
    height: 70px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    bottom: 90px;
}
```

Live preview: http://funedit.com/andurit/new/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the href have the following css:

```
position:relative;
bottom:90px;
```

Instead of the `shorttext`.

e.g. Using your code change the HTML to the following:

```
 <div class="left">
    <img src="images/slider.png">
    <a href="#" class="shorttexthref"><span class="shorttext"><h4>V posledných dnech se událo mnoho změn, které byli velice výrazné. Proto neváhajte a podívete se i vy na to, co se vlastne zmenilo a nebo nezměnilo kdo vi... </h4></span></a>
  </div>
```

Change the `.shorttext` and add the `.shorttexthref` CSS:

```
.shorttext{
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    width: 415px;
    height: 70px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
} 
.shorttexthref {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 90px;}
```